# child method defined on parent method in constructor's prototype returns `undefined` for object's property accessed via this. Why

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

In the following code, `getName()` method defined on constructor's prototype has a child method `getAge()` defined on it (because it's a `function object`, I think so) however `typeof emp1.getName == "object"` returns `false` but `emp1.getName.hasOwnProperty('getAge')` returns `true`.

```
var fname = "Ram";
var lname = "Singh";
var age = "48";

function employee(fname, lname, age) {
  this.fname = fname;
  this.lname = lname;
  this.age = age;
}
employee.prototype.getName = function () { return "Name is: " + this.fname + " " + this.lname; },
employee.prototype.getName.getAge = "function () { return + this.age; }"

var emp1 = new employee(fname, lname, age);
typeof emp1.getName == "object";        //returns false
emp1.getName.hasOwnProperty('getAge');   //returns true
```

If `getName` isn't a object then how can it have a child property `getAge` as it's own property.

Moreover, `emp1.getName.getAge()` returns `Age is: undefined` but `emp1.age` was initialized with `48` since `emp1.age` returns `48` so why `getAge()` fails to get `emp1.age` value.

Comment: The `this` in `getAge` is not the instance of `employee`. Have you tried logging it?

Answer (score 0):

`getName` is a function (try `typeof emp1.getName == 'function'`) which is a particular kind of object (almost everything is a object on javascript). As so, it can also have its own properties.

Comment: yeah, but it's essentially an object as you rightly said almost everything is a object on javascript. Moreover that object has a property `getAge()` added, which makes it more obvious as `functions` per say do not have properties but objects do